# Integrate Dropbox into my website

Tags: php, json, dropbox

I've done some googling around on this topic, but there seems to be only one option: the Dropbox official API. Is there no other way i could do some sort of JSON/PHP get_file_contents etc, when you get tweets from twitter you can use the user_timeline, is there no alternative for Dropbox people have come across. I just want something i can put a username and password into the PHP script and have it get the files (or am i dreaming and will have to use the API)

Comment: Exactly why don't you want to use the dropbox API? What you're trying to do should be quite simple using the php api: http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/wiki/Dropbox_API

Comment: Its not that i dont want to use it, my question is are there any alternatives

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [Dropbox PHP SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/php) it uses OAuth for validation which is the safest way.

Answer (score 2):

You're dreaming and will have to use the API. This is exactly what API's are for, for programming applications to talk to applications. Specifically on the subject of authentication, there would be so many security issues with just having a user/pass in your code it's not even funny. Things like OAuth and other API authentication methods exist to make this kind of thing safer and saner. Sort of like lighting a campfire in a firepit instead of the middle of a dry grassland.

There are libraries like the one fire mentions that can wrap the API and make it easier to access from your language, but you need to play by the rulebook here. I know it sounds daunting but your application will be the better for doing it right.

Comment: exactly, its like asking "how can I generate a google map without using the google maps API?"

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the hosting service [KISSR](http://www.kissr.co/) which would allow you to host your entire site out of Dropbox. This would be simpler than using the API but you wouldn't be able to use PHP.

Answer (score 0):

it is not that much of a odd question that has been asked. as if you are using two hosting services one of them for just hosting images the other is for interaction events, done gazillions of time, some servers use term 'content/image leeching', hard to differenciate legit useage. however thats what consumer is asking/requesting, funny answers